# Insert Animated GIF into Powerpoint 2013?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, animated-gif, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

As per title, I am looking for a way to embed animated GIF files within my powerpoint presentation.  I was hoping for this to be native functionality but either inserting as image or as video does not appear to work.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can add any animated `*.gif` by just drag and drop from explorer window, or in the ribbon UI click `Insert - Pictures` and navigate to your `gif` image, and click `Insert`. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> to begin the slideshow. *Make sure your GIF file is animating by opening it with Internet Explorer, because static GIFs never animate.*

Here's the MS Powerpoint 2013 demonstration:
[image]

Comment: Do you know a way to keep the GIF also playing when you format it with some style effects (like a border)? in office 2007 it worked, but I could not identify a way for 2013 so far

Comment: Love the way you reply with an animated gif; +1

Comment: Hey Isaac, awesome reply! What the software you use to produce this animated gif?

Comment: @ClickOk It's LiceCap. [http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Graphic/Graphic-Capture/LICEcap.shtml](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Graphic/Graphic-Capture/LICEcap.shtml)

Comment: What about .PNG?